# Spring Bean for static classes

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to understand drawbacks of my design , below is my code

```
class Utils {
    public static SpringBean bean;
    public static void setBean(SpringBean b){
        bean = b;
    } 
    public static SpringBean getBean(){
        return bean;
    }
    public static Object getSomethingFromBean(){
        return bean.getSomethingFromBean();
    }
}
```

Below is my bean context xml

```
<bean id="utils" class="utils">
    <property name="bean" ref="springBean"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="springBean" class="SpringBean">
</bean>
```

I am doing this so I can directly call methods of utils class like ,

```
Utils.getSomethingFromBean();
```

Comment: Why would you want this? What is the use case? In your example _`utils.getSomethingFromBean()`_ you are calling a `static method on an instance of `Utils` - so why does the method need to be `static` in the first place?

Comment: There is no particular use case , just trying to understand the drawbacks of doing this .  also i changed the utils to Utils.

Comment: One word, the most important word you'll ever hear when it comes to writing modern Java - **testability**.

Answer (score 4):

The point of Spring is (simplifying here) to avoid accessing the services through static methods or singletons. All reasons for using Spring apply to why not to use this approach.

Also, having to instantiate a static-fields-only class is a good hint that you're doing something at least unusual.

And last, as presented it doesn't make sense to have the content of `Utils` static - you can do `utils.getSomethingFromBean();` just as well if `Utils` is a normal bean with no static fields. If your intention is to be able to call `Utils.getSomethingFromBean();`, you should make `utils` Spring bean available to the caller rather than resorting to static methods.

Comment: i made a mistake in writing ... i am not instantiating the class . it is Utils.getSomethingFromBean();

Comment: You are in fact instantiating it, or more exactly, Spring is. Your XML instructs Spring to create an instance of `Utils`, just so that it can then call a method on it that writes into the static field.

Comment: I thought the default scope of Sping is singleton. What do you mean when you say Spring avoid accessing singletons?

Comment: @NothingBox That depends on your understanding of what a "singleton" means - in Spring, `scope="singleton"` means that whenever you use the bean's name in a reference (or request it from the container), you get the same instance. The "singleton" from the post's first sentence is the Java singleton in the general sense of that term - i.e. a class that only ever has one instance in the JVM.